# Expand div when node is selected

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a basic p:tree which visualize components from database. I want to expand the tree this way:
[image]

When I select a node I want to open div layer below the component and display additional data to this component as the picture. So far I made this JSF code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl1" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" cached="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <p:tree id="tree" styleClass="treeskin" value="#{TreeViewController.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" animate="true"
            selectionMode="single"  selection="#{TreeViewController.selectedNode}" highlight="true">

        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeSelect}"/>
        <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeExpand}" />
        <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeCollapse}" />

        <p:treeNode styleClass="treeskin">
            <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>

</h:form>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably you're looking for `p:outputPanel` tag with `modal` attribute set to true. If not, just put the `p:outputPanel` in your right frame and render its content dinamically acording to the selected node. But I think breaking the tree in the way you want is just a way to complicate it.

Comment: Would you give some example code, please?

Comment: `<p:ajax event="select" listener="#{TreeViewController.onNodeSelect} update="infoPanel" />`. `infoPanel` will be the main panel which contains the info about the node.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I made example with div layer positioned at the right side of the browser. But I'm interested how I can insert the div layer directly into the tree and expanding it when I click on a tree node.

Comment: I know, I was giving you an easy alternative to do something similar. Note that `p:treeNode` is a prebuilt component, doing what you want requires creating your own component extending that or modifying it in client side by tricky javascript. Take a look at this guide for customizing your components http://mrbool.com/customizing-components-in-jsf-2-0/23854

Comment: Alternative solution: Can I for example get the position of the selected tree node using JavaScript. I can call JavasCript code with the attribute `onNodeClick` and then position the div on the right side of the tree. But how this can be done with JavaScript? I want when I click on a tree node to display div with data.

Comment: You have to inspect the structure of the tree you're building at client side and after modify it with javascript, being called with that event. Not very elegant, but..